# Python - List Index Out Of Range In For Loop

Tags: python, string, list

I'm fairly new to python and I'm currently working on a program that will encrypt and decrypt strings. As part of it, I need the individual letters of the string to each be added to an empty list; for example, the string 'hello' would be entered into a list list like so:

```
['h','e','l','l','o']
```

The part of the code that is giving me this error can be found below. Thanks.

```
emptyList=[]
message=input("What Would You Like To Encrypt?\n")

messageLength=len(message)
for count in range(0,messageLength):
        emptyList=[]
        emptyList[count].append(message[count])
```

Comment: `emptyList[0]` does not exist when `emptyList` is `[]`. You might want to `empyList.append(message[count])`. That said, it'd likely be easier to do `emptyList = list(message)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to address indices in an empty list:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> lst[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

If you wanted to *add* elements to a list, just use `list.append()` directly on the list object itself to create more indices; don't create new empty lists each time:

```
emptyList=[]
messageLength=len(message)
for count in range(0,messageLength):
    emptyList.append(message[count])
```

Not that you need to be this elaborate, the following is enough:

```
emptyList = list(message)
```

`list()` takes any iterable and adds all the elements of that iterable to a list. Since a string is iterable, producing all the characters in that string, calling `list()` on a string creates a list of those characters:

```
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want just read from the input and then output a list

## Python 2.7

```
message=raw_input("What Would You Like To Encrypt?\n")
print list(message)
```

## Python 3.X

```
message=input("What Would You Like To Encrypt?\n")
print(list(message))
```

## Output

If you input Hello

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```